# not found: value dao compilation error on saving json object in PostgreSQL database using Play Framework and Scala?

Tags: jquery, json, postgresql, scala, playframework

Please help me regarding how can I save my json object in database like PostgreSQL using Play Framework, Scala and jQuery/ajax if possible ? I have done the following trials and getting compilation error like: not found: value dao, and then later I am not sure that what to do to save my json object in database(either any other business logic or persistence logic or ajax calls or any I am missing) ? I need your support to do this.

routes file:

```
POST    /json                       @controllers.Application.saveJsonData
```

App.Scala file:

```
def saveJsonData = Action { request => 
  val body: AnyContext = request.body
  val jsonBody: Option[JsValue] = body.asJson
  jsonBody.map {json =>
    dao.persist(json) // stores in database, not found: dao
    Ok("Saved") 
 }.getOrElse {
   BadRequest("Expecting text/json request.body")  
  }
}
```

app.conf:

```
db.default.driver=org.postgresql.Driver
db.default.url="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/database"
db.default.user=test
db.default.password=1234
```

Build.scala:

```
val appDependencies = Seq(
    "org.postgresql" % "postgresql" % "9.4-1200-jdbc41",
    "postgresql" % "postgresql" % "9.1-901.jdbc4"
    )
```

html:

```
(function() {
  var buttonValue = {};
  $("#submit").click(function() {
    $("input[type=button], input[type=file]").each(function($i) {
      var name = $(this).attr('name')
      buttonValue[name] = $(this).val();
    });
    console.log(JSON.stringify(buttonValue));//json object: [ex: {"firstButton":"button1","secondButton":"button2","file":"test.txt"} ], this json object should store in PostgreSQL database table as it is after clicking of Submit button.
  });
}())

<input type='submit' value='Submit Json' id='submitJson'>
```

database table:

```
create table saveJsonData(id integer primary key, content json);
```

Comment: Have you imported the dao class? edit: Where is your jdbc dependency?

Comment: @PiNg2Eiw, thanks for your reply, I didn't write any jdbc dependency, as I am not aware of those thing with Play and Postgresql.So, I am looking for a solution either using jdbc or any directly that we can save in database ?

Comment: You might want to take a look at the documentation: https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.0.x/ScalaDatabase

Comment: @rethab, can I have any example on it to access and store some data in database ?